# AngularJS error when POST but works after refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this function in my controller that sends a POST request to the database (SQLite). The function is bound to a `ng-click` in the html and when I try to add I get a 500 Internal server error. Then if I refresh the page the new item appears. Why is this happening?

```
app.controller("Ctrl", ["$scope", "$q", "$log", "$http", "dataService", function($scope, $q, $log, $http, dataService) {
  $log.debug("Initializing Controller");

  $scope.good = [];

  $scope.addGood = function(body) {
    $log.debug($scope.good.length+1);
    $log.debug(body);
    $http.post('/goods', {
        'id': "2",
        'body': "yey",
        'author': "suh",
        'date': "suh"
    });
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get a 500 Internal server error.

It means some code is giving error in your API (back-end).

> Then if I refresh the page the new item appears.

It means in your back-end, your API is inserting the object (data you're sending from front-end) correctly.

And as you haven't provided us with the back-end (API) code, I can only assume that something is going wrong over there after it inserts the data in SQLite.

Please have a look there, you will get the solution or post your code in your question.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What this means is that the server method to handle the POST request is encountering an error. You get a 500 error (which really only means: "Something went wrong on the server, go look at the server logs").

Clearly the server method saved the record to SQLite ok, and something failed after that. I say that, because the page refresh shows the data has been stored ok.

Comment: I have no idea where the error may be though. Also if it's updating the db how come the table isn't auto updating?

Comment: its because your table in DOM is not binded with your DB but with the scope of your angular application